# How to close angular bootstrap typeahead when multiple fields with the typeahead exist?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using angular bootstrap typeahead. I need typeahead on multiple input fields. Is there some option I can use that I am missing out on? Or do I need to add something hacky to achieve this?

The two fields look like this [image: multiple dropdowns]:

```
<label>
     Sector&nbsp;
     <span class="restrict-dropdown-menu-small">
       <input type="text" class="form-control length-md" 
                          ng-model="customBenchmark.sector"
                          typeahead="sector for sector in customBenchmarkOptions.sectors | filter:$viewValue:$emptyOrMatch | orderBy:'toString()'"
                          typeahead-focus
                          typeahead-select-on-blur="true"/>
     </span>
</label>
<label>
      Rating&nbsp;
      <span class="restrict-dropdown-menu-small">
          <input type="text" class="form-control length-md"
                             ng-model="customBenchmark.rating"
                             typeahead="rating for rating in customBenchmarkOptions.ratings | filter:$viewValue:$emptyOrMatch | orderBy:'toString()'"
                             typeahead-focus
                             typeahead-select-on-blur="true"/>
      </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Have same bug. This appears on Firefox only in my case.
This has something to do with promise resolve, if using static data, then dropdown is closed properly.